# listview does not update with setState

Tags: flutter, listview, setstate

I have a card with a TexField and a button to select an image.
After the image has been selected, the icon must be replaced by the image and in the selection dialog the item delete must be displayed.
It works perfectly on the first card that is fixed, but on cards inserted dynamically in Listview it doesn't work because it doesn't update with setState.
How to update the listView?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: NewPollPage(),
    ));

class NewPollPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPollPageState createState() => _NewPollPageState();
}

class _NewPollPageState extends State<NewPollPage> {
  Map photoMap = {};
  var cards = <Card>[];
  var newAlt = <TextEditingController>[];
  var alternativaController = TextEditingController();
  var alternativa1Controller = TextEditingController();

  String indice = UniqueKey().toString();
  File cropped;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text('Cards'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              elevation: 0,
              color: Color(0xFAFAFA),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  !photoMap.containsKey('foto_n1')
                      ? IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                          color: Colors.black,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectImage(context, 'n1', false);
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      : GestureDetector(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                            width: 50,
                            height: 46,
                            child: Image.file(photoMap['foto_n1']),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectImage(context, 'n1', true);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: alternativa1Controller,
                      maxLength: 60,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Digite a alternativa',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 22),
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE3E4E8),
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: cards.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                indice = UniqueKey().toString();
                return cards[index];
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => cards.add(createCard(indice)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Card createCard(indice) {
    var alternativaController = TextEditingController();
    newAlt.add(alternativaController);
    return Card(
      elevation: 0,
      color: Color(0xFAFAFA),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          !photoMap.containsKey('foto_$indice')
              ? IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectImage(context, '$indice', false);
                    });
                  },
                )
              : GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                    width: 50,
                    height: 46,
                    child: Image.file(photoMap['foto_$indice']),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectImage(context, '$indice', true);
                    });
                  },
                ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              maxLength: 60,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Digite a alternativa',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 22),
                fillColor: Color(0xFFE3E4E8),
                filled: true,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  selectImage(parentContext, indice, visivel) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: Text('Selecione:'),
            children: [
              if (photoMap.containsKey('foto_$indice'))
                Image.file(photoMap['foto_$indice']),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                      Text('  Tirar foto com a câmera'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => getImage(ImageSource.camera, indice)),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                      Text('  Foto da galeria'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => getImage(ImageSource.gallery, indice)),
              Visibility(
                visible: visivel,
                child: SimpleDialogOption(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.delete),
                        Text('  Apagar'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => null //apagarFoto(mapa),
                    ),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    Text('  Cancelar'),
                  ],
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  Future getImage(ImageSource source, indice) async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    PickedFile imagePicker = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);
    if (imagePicker != null) {
      cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: imagePicker.path,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 4, ratioY: 3),
        compressQuality: 70,
        maxWidth: 700,
        maxHeight: 700,
        compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarColor: Colors.black,
          toolbarTitle: "Foto",
          statusBarColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          dimmedLayerColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      );
      if (cropped != null) {
        setState(() {
          photoMap['foto_$indice'] = cropped;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a widget in List which is going to update later on. Instead you should have a function that will return your widget based on index of list.

Instead of

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: cards.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            indice = UniqueKey().toString();
            return cards[index];
          },
        )
```

You should do

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: photoMap.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _cardWidget(index);
          },
        )
```

In _cardWidget function

```
Card _cardWidget(int index) {
return Card(
  elevation: 0,
  color: Color(0xFAFAFA),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      photoMap['foto_$index'] == ''
          ? IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectImage(context, '$index', false);
                });
              },
            )
          : GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                width: 50,
                height: 46,
                child: Image.file(photoMap['foto_$index']),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectImage(context, '$index', true);
                });
              },
            ),
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          maxLength: 60,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Digite a alternativa',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 22),
            fillColor: Color(0xFFE3E4E8),
            filled: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
   }
```

adding key in photoMap with empty string for comparison whether it contains file or not

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() => photoMap["foto_${photoMap.length}"] = '');
    },
  ),
```

changing compare logic in selectImage

```
  if (photoMap['foto_$indice'] != '')Image.file(photoMap['foto_$indice']),
```

Comment: great, it works fine.

thank you very much.